# Get X & Y Coordinates of Camera Focus

Tags: android, android-camera, getpixel

I would like to ask a question related to the camera live view.

When we tap somewhere on the camera preview, a focus appears. How should I get the X & Y coordinates or pixel of that focus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusAreas%28%29) gives list of all focus areas and try to get [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) of each focus area by which you could get (x,y) of the rectangle.